# Querying the firebase database based on child's value

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is the snapshot of the firebase database

[image: Firebase Snapshot]

I have only the 'name' field with me. I need to get the 'quantity' value of that 'name'.
What is the firebase query to fetch the quantity for a specific name (in javascript). Please help me out with this.

Comment: have you checked the answer?

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the data according to the `name` attribute then do the following:

```
let ref = firebase.database().ref("Categories").child("Burgers");
ref.orderByChild("name").equalTo("Egg Burger").on("value", function(snapshot) {
 snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
  var childData = childSnapshot.val();
  console.log(childData.quantity);
 });
})
```

Add a reference to node `Burgers`, then you can do a query `orderByChild` and use the `name` attribute to check if it is equal to a value, attach a listener to it and retrieve the value of `quantity`.